# How to thaw/defrost a frozen object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Could you please show me how to defrost a frozen object in Javascript, so that I will be able to modify its properties?

```
var pizza = {
    name: 'Peri Peri',
    Topping: 'Prawn'
};

Object.freeze(pizza);

// Can't change the name of the object because it's frozen
pizza.name = 'Hawaiian';
```

Comment: What would be the point of freezing an object if it could be simply unfrozen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#Description) makes an object immutable. Quoting from that page,

> Nothing can be added to or removed from the properties set of a frozen
>   object. Any attempt to do so will fail, either silently or by throwing
>   a TypeError exception (most commonly, but not exclusively, when in
>   strict mode).
>
> Values cannot be changed for data properties. Accessor properties
>   (getters and setters) work the same (and still give the illusion that
>   you are changing the value). Note that values that are objects can
>   still be modified, unless they are also frozen.

So, the only way this could be done is, by cloning the object

```
var pizza = {
    name: 'Peri Peri',
    Topping: 'Prawn'
};

Object.freeze(pizza);
pizza.name = 'Hawaiian';
console.log(pizza);
// { name: 'Peri Peri', Topping: 'Prawn' }

pizza = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pizza));  // Clones the object

pizza.name = 'Hawaiian';
console.log(pizza);
// { name: 'Hawaiian', Topping: 'Prawn' }
```

**Note 1:** In strict mode, it will *NOT* fail silently and throw an Error instead

```
"use strict";
...
...
pizza.name = 'Hawaiian';
           ^
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of #<Object>
```

**Note 2:** If your object has methods, then `JSON.stringify` approach will *NOT* get them. You can read more about properly cloning the objects in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774008/cloning-a-javascript-object).

Comment: Wouldn't using `Object.create` be shorter and faster than using JSON?

Comment: @DanD. But I cannot clone with `Object.create`, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can't: [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

> Freezing an object is the ultimate form of lock-down. Once an object
>   has been frozen it cannot be unfrozen – nor can it be tampered in any
>   manner. This is the best way to make sure that your objects will stay
>   exactly as you left them, indefinitely.

From a similiar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19293418/1420186

Comment: You just copied this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293321/opposite-of-object-freeze-or-object-seal-in-javascript

Comment: yeah thats why he put it in `blockquote`