# Calling an overridden and frozen function

Tags: javascript

I'm building a security framework which injects a javascript file which will always be executed first, and blocks some functions to be executed.
The developers will make their own webapps and the script will make sure that some functionalities cannot be called.

Let's suppose the "blocking" script is like this:

```
window.alert = function(){Object.freeze(this)}
```

Is there any way for an application to circumvent this block, without using iframes/external files?
delete(window.alert) doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: You've overwritten the alert method, so no, there's no longer any way to get the original alert back.

Comment: When calling `alert()`, first `Object.free` then original JS `alert` function shall be executed, right?

Comment: You could write a new window alert method and have it output to the console or display in an HTML element visible on your page.

Comment: If you only need `alert()` to annoy the users, you can as well use `prompt()` (if it hasn't been overwritten)

Comment: alert() was just an example for a more general concept @maja

Comment: it might make more sense and help more people to explain the issue if the actual `alert` thing is just an example

Comment: If you are absolutly sure that your code is always run first, you only have to ensure that you don't forget to freeze/remove everything that might get dangerous (which might be a harder task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `alert` property on `Window.prototype`, not on `window`. Otherwise:

```
Window.prototype.alert.call(window, 'This works.');
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually made the alert appear! I don't know why you're getting downvoted.

Comment: @Thom Smith really sorry for the downvote (playing with my mouse during a phone call...) again I used your code to update my fiddle. Apparently I can undo to upvote during 24h unless you edit your answer...  sorry again

Answer (score 2):

not if you can't stop that script running first, otherwise you could asign the original `alert` to something else:

```
var oldAlert = window.alert;
window.alert = function(){Object.freeze(this)}
```

How/why are you using `alert`? if its for debugging you'd be better off using `console.log`. if you are using it to notify users then maybe a dedicated modal would be the better option

Based on your updated question, it depends how your framework is loaded.

Lets say you provide the script to the developer to use, in that case they could very easily alter what your script does. if the code is running on in a env that isn't yours then you can assume it's not secure. browser plugins can block scripts, there would bypass any security based in a javascript file.

Comment: Follow up question: if override the alert right at the beginning of HEAD, is there any way to execute code before it (assuming the first script inside head will always be the alert-blocking one) ? 
Maybe some event I ignore of the kind of onLoad()
Thanks!

Comment: javascript is executing in order, just write it in the order you want it to run

Comment: But the point is that I cannot change the order, the script will always be first. In this case then I can't do anything?

Comment: can you fully explain the problem you have hit, as it sounds like overwriting alert is just a basic example. why cant you change the order?, are they auto generated?, is it a cms? the more info the better the answer

Answer (score 1):

based on the work of @Abdennour TOUMI on this post : [Opposite of Object.freeze or Object.seal in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293321/opposite-of-object-freeze-or-object-seal-in-javascript/26752410#26752410), you can do something like that :

```
window.alert = function(){Object.freeze(this)} ;

Object.unfreezeAlert=function(){
       return window.prompt;
 }

window.alert = Object.unfreezeAlert(window.alert);
alert ('test4');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scraaappy/pxv51zqg/

Comment: however, I've noticed a strange behavior I've notified in the fiddle

Comment: Yeah and moreover you are replacing an alert with a prompt, so the alert is actually still blocked.

Comment: no, that's not the trouble. See the fiddle, alert is currently re-activated (thanks to @Thom Smith), but check comment in it , there is a unexpected behavior : if you call alert before trying to unfreeze, it won't work. I'm interested if you have any explanation about that. Anyway I though the interest was mainly to reaffect alert method rather than reactivate it.